# Cannot run bundle update or bundle install on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, bundler

I am trying to deploy a Ruby app from my WSL Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on Windows 10.0.19042 Build 19042.

Whether I do `bundle install` or `bundle update`, I keep running into the same odd issue:

```
djob@mylocal-LTW:/mnt/c/Users/djob/workspace/heroku/fix-store$ /usr/local/bin/bundle update --verbose
Fetching git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Retrying git clone 'git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git' "/home/djob/.bundler/cache/git/spree_gateway-6119aa63b6a7211640621de5f05ec34760ee7fe4" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git' "/home/djob/.bundler/cache/git/spree_gateway-6119aa63b6a7211640621de5f05ec34760ee7fe4" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /mnt/c/Users/djob/workspace/heroku/fix-store has failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Retrying git clone 'git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git' "/home/djob/.bundler/cache/git/spree_gateway-6119aa63b6a7211640621de5f05ec34760ee7fe4" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (3/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git' "/home/djob/.bundler/cache/git/spree_gateway-6119aa63b6a7211640621de5f05ec34760ee7fe4" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /mnt/c/Users/djob/workspace/heroku/fix-store has failed.
```

What could the root cause be? The git repos do exist. I am on ruby 2.7.0p0 `(2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.7.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'puma'

gem 'pg'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'rack-cors'

gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end


gem 'spree', '3.0.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'

gem 'dalli'
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your gemfile look like?

Comment: How did you fetch the repo? via Git? Or have you manually downloaded it to your folder?

Comment: @TaimoorHassan via git

Comment: @Beartech I just added it

Comment: You either do not have permissions to clone this from the repository, or you do not have permissions to clone to the destination folder. I recommend simply do shh to your server and try cloning it directly, without bundler

Comment: Yes but that doesn't make sense. It's a public repo. I can browse to it and I can git clone locally. I'll try what you suggested and take it from there, thanks